# Meaning of end= in print() call

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between

```
print(a, end='  ')
```

and

```
print(a, '  ')
```

in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is really unclear -- can you please update it to be more specific about what you're looking for? (and also clarify whether the question is about python or jquery, since you've mentioned one but tagged the other)...

Comment: Print an other string afterwards and you will notice.

Answer (score 3):

`end` is a keyword-only argument to the `print` function that declares what value will be tacked onto the end of the print statement. By default this is `"\n"` (a newline).

Passing multiple values to print joins them together using `str.join` with the keyword-only `sep` argument (defaulting to `' '`) as the separator, so...

```
print(a, ' ')     # prints the value of str(a) ' '.join'ed with a space
                  # then terminated with a newline
"a  \n"

print(a, ' ', sep="SEPARATOR")  # produces...
"aSEPARATOR \n"

print(a, end=' ') # prints the value of a, terminated with a space
"a "
```